# get outer range of number sequence

Tags: unix, awk

I have a column of numbers such as:

2
3
4
5
8
9
10

I would like to output something similar to 2-5 and 8-10 for my column of numbers.  This doesn't seem like it should be that difficult, but I lack the skill.  Using awk I have attempted to create a column of difference such as below and use it to capture the ranges but cannot get things to work.

2 0
3 1
4 1
5 1
8 3
9 1
10 1

```
startNumber = $1

{ if ($2 > 1) { print "Start Number", startNumber } else {
    if ($2 <= 1) endNumber=$1
    }
} {print "printing the endNumber", endNumber}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try

```
awk -f range.awk input.txt
```

where

`input.txt` is your input file and `range.awk` is

```
NR==1 { first=$1; prev=first; next }
{
    if ($1-prev != 1) {
        if (f) printf "%d-%d\n",first,prev
        first=$1; f=0
    } else f=1
    prev=$1; 
}
END {
    if (f) printf "%d-%d\n",first,prev
}
```

Comment: Given input `1 3 5`, this will output `1-1`, `3-3`, `5-5`.  You just need to adjust the printing so if `prev == first` you print one number and two numbers otherwise.

Comment: Instead of `if (f) printf "%d-%d\n",first,prev`, I think you need `if (prev == first) printf "%d\n", first; else printf "%d-%d\n", first, prev;`. The revision with `f` produces no output for 1 3 5.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure, I see your point. I just realized I was thinking wrongly about the expected output.. Anyway, I think I will not updating the answer since it might be just a minor issue.. I expect the original poster can figure out what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
$ awk '1{if (NR==1) {a=$0; print $0, 0} else {print $0, $0-a; a=$0}}' test
2 0
3 1
4 1
5 1
8 3
9 1
10 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Some like this?

```
awk '{print $1,$1-a;a=$1}' file
2 2
3 1
4 1
5 1
8 3
9 1
10 1
```

If you like 0 after 2, you can do:

```
awk 'NR==1 {a=$1} {print $1,$1-a;a=$1}' file
2 0
3 1
4 1
5 1
8 3
9 1
10 1
```